# Ruby Factory Method rpsec temperature converter

Tags: ruby

not quite understanding factory method here...
here is the respec line:

```
Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_celsius.should == 50
```

Here is what I have now:

getting errors...not quite sure how to satisfy this. thanks

```
class Temperature
attr_accessor :f
attr_accessor :c   

   def initialize(args)
     @f = args[:f]
     @c = args[:c]
   end

  def in_fahrenheit
     @f or
    (@c*9.0/5.0)+32 
  end

  def in_celsius

   @c or
  (@f-32)*(5.0/9.0)
   end

   def self.from_celsius(c)
    new c
    end


   end
```

Comment: Can you post what errors you are getting?

Comment: ArgumentError:
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: It looks like you're confusing class and instance methods here, but it's hard to tell. Could you reformat the code so that it is more readable?

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
class Temperature
  def initialize c
    @c = c
  end

  def in_celsius
    @c
  end

  def in_fahrenheit
    @c *9.0 /5.0 +32
  end

  # factory pattern typically instantiates a new object
  def self.from_celsius(c)
    new c
  end
end

puts Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_celsius      #=> 50
puts Temperature.from_celsius(100).in_fahrenheit  #=> 212
```

I would recommend against `attr_accessor :c` unless you want users to have public access to `temp.c`. Without it, users will be forced to use `temp.in_celsius` or `temp.in_fahrenheit`

Comment: I'm getting: TypeError:
can't convert Symbol into Integer

Comment: What are you trying to run through it? The code in my post runs in ruby 1.8.7 through 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign to :c in the initialize method. Then you need self.from_celsius to return a new instance of Temperature. You probably want something like this:

```
class Temperature
  attr_accessor :c
  def initialize c
    @c = c
  end

  def in_celsius
    @c
  end

  def in_fahrenheit
    9/5 * @c + 32
  end

  def self.from_celsius(num)
    Temperature.new(num)
  end

  def self.from_fahrenheit(num)
    Temperature.new((num-32)*5/9)
  end
end
```

Now rspec shows true

```
1.9.1p378 :047 > Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_celsius.should == 50
 => true 
1.9.1p378 :131 > Temperature.from_fahrenheit(32).in_celsius.should == 0
 => true
```

Comment: i wonder whys thats now working on my end....im getting an error: Can't covert symbol to integer

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: 1.8.7....also this is the practice i'm trying to tackle...http://testfirst.org/live/learn_ruby/temperature_object. i've updated my code to exactly what i have

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting "error: Can't covert symbol to integer –" is because you're in your Temperature.from_celsius(50) you're passing it an integer when you're supposed to pass it a key & symbol for the options hash.

*initialized*

```
class Temperature
  def initialize(opts = {})
    @options = opts
  end
```

*class factory method*

```
def self.from_celsius(x)
    Temperature.new(:c => x)
end
```

*instance method*

```
def in_celsius
    if @options[:c] == nil
      return (@options[:f]-32) * (5/9.to_f)
    else
      return @options[:c]
  end
end
```